# Sweet alert funciona en algunas partes y en otras no

Tags: php, javascript, sweetalert

El sweet alert de abajo, cuando un usuario se registra si me lo muestra pero el de arriba no. Lo raro es que cuando uso alerta normal esa si me sale, por ellos supongo que el problema es con sweet alert y no mi codigo php

```html
require("conexion.php");
//la variable  $mysqli viene de connect_db que lo traigo con el require("connect_db.php");
 $checkemail=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM login WHERE email='$mail'");
 $check_mail=mysqli_num_rows($checkemail);
  if($clave==$clave)
        {
   if($check_mail>0)
            {
    echo "<script> 
                        swal({ 
                        title: 'ATENCION!',
                        text: 'Ya existe el mail designado para un usuario, verifique sus datos',
                        icon: 'warning',
                        button: 'Aceptar',
                        });
                      </script>";
   }
            else
            {
    //require("connect_db.php");
                //la variable  $mysqli viene de connect_db que lo traigo con el require("connect_db.php");
    mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO login VALUES('','$nombre', '$apellido', '$clave','$mail', '$fechaNac', '','','2')");
                
                
                    //echo 'Se ha registrado con exito';
                    echo "<script> 
                          swal({ 
                          title: 'HECHO!',
                          text: 'Usuario registrado con exito',
                          icon: 'success',
                          button: 'Aceptar',
                          });
                          </script>";
   }
  }
```

Comment: ¿Te muestra algún error en la consola?

Comment: Me sale esto: Uncaught(admin.php:2)
ReferenceError: swal is not defined
 at admin.php:2

Me sale por un instante y se quita por que es un actualizar que hago nadamas que quiero mostrar un mensaje de que se realizo correctamente pero tengo este error.